# File not closing in node.js before upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, fs

I'm trying to upload a file to S3 after creation however the file doesn't seem to be closing with the fs.createWriteStream. Hence I keep getting a 0 byte file being uploaded.

```
function createManifest(manfile) {
console.log(['a'].toString(), ['a', 'b'].toString());

    var arrayLength = files.length;
    var lastItem = arrayLength - 1;
    console.log( chalk.blue("The last item value is:",lastItem))
    console.log( chalk.yellow("The arrayLength value is:",arrayLength))
    var logStream = fs.createWriteStream("manny_temp.json", {'flags': 'a'});
// use {'flags': 'a'} to append and {'flags': 'w'} to erase and write a new file
//    logStream.on('open', function(fd) {
logStream.write('{'+ "\r\n");
logStream.write("\"entries\": [" + "\r\n");

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

            console.log( chalk.inverse(files[i]))
            console.log( chalk.blue("The i value is:",i))
            if ( i == lastItem) {
                logStream.write("{\"url\":\"s3://mybucket/" +files[i] + "\",\"key\":true}" + "\r\n");
            } else {
                    logStream.write("{\"url\":\"s3://mybucket/" +files[i] + "\",\"key\":true}," + "\r\n");
             }
    }
    logStream.write('    ]' + "\r\n");
    logStream.write('}');
//      }).on('end', function() {
            logStream.end();
            //fs.renameSync(logStream.path, manfile.toString());
            return callback(filepath);
//      logStream.close();
    //fs.renameSync(logStream.path, "manny.json");

  //   });
}
```

I've tried a multitude of ways to get the file to close so that the next function can upload the file upon creation, and even added a sleep, but it always seems to leave a hanging inode.

Using the fs.write seems to write only one line vs writing all the lines in the array / streaming data.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: please clean up your sample code and make it readable at a glance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to listen for the `close` event on the `logStream` before calling the callback. That is what signals that the backing file descriptor has been closed (no more writing will take place). I should note, this is different than listening for the `finish` event since `finish` merely indicates the stream is closed, but not necessarily that the file descriptor is closed, so it is technically less safe to rely on if you're going to do something with the file soon after).

Replace this:

```
return callback(filepath);
```

with this:

```
logStream.on('close', function() {
  callback(filepath);
});
```

It is possible to improve on this further, by instead using the `(err, result)`-style callbacks common in the node ecosystem:

```
logStream.on('close', function() {
  callback(null, filepath);
});
logStream.on('error', function(err) {
  callback(err);
});
```

That way you can capture any errors that may result from opening or writing to the file.

I'm also assuming you *do* have `callback` defined in a parent scope somewhere.

Comment: This should work adam.  Also you should note the reason you're seeing this behavior.  Node.js is asynchronous.  So logStream is ended even before your for loop is finished its iterations.  Consider doing some research before implementing the above.

Comment: btw `callback` is not defined in Adam's code, So he could not use it. His question is very raw, it should be improvised else nobody could understand & answer ;)

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni if `callback` was truly undefined, they would have seen an exception thrown immediately upon executing the `createManifest()` function. Since they did not mention such an error, I believe it's safe to assume it is probably defined in a parent scope.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is asked without the basic research though, Here is an attempt to make it more readable code and executable at glance. Hope you will find an answer with below code.

If your question is still the same, re-write your question in a better way.

```
var chalk = require('chalk');
var fs = require('fs');

function createManifest(manfile) {
var files = ['/test.json'];
console.log(['a'].toString(), ['a', 'b'].toString());
    var arrayLength = files.length;
    var lastItem = arrayLength - 1;
    console.log( chalk.blue("The last item value is:",lastItem))
    console.log( chalk.yellow("The arrayLength value is:",arrayLength))
    var logStream = fs.createWriteStream("manny_temp.json", {'flags': 'a'});
    logStream.write('{'+ "\r\n");
    logStream.write("\"entries\": [" + "\r\n");

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

            console.log( chalk.inverse(files[i]))
            console.log( chalk.blue("The i value is:",i))
            if ( i == lastItem) {
                logStream.write("{\"url\":\"s3://mybucket/" +files[i] + "\",\"key\":true}" + "\r\n");
            } else {
                    logStream.write("{\"url\":\"s3://mybucket/" +files[i] + "\",\"key\":true}," + "\r\n");
             }
    }
    logStream.write('    ]' + "\r\n");
    logStream.write('}'); 
    logStream.end();
    logStream.on('finish', function(){
        fs.renameSync("manny_temp.json", "manny.json"); 
    }); 
};

createManifest();
```

Comment: Even with subsituting your function for mine I still seem to run into the same issue that I was having before with the other fixes I was trying which is the error:
`code`
    fs.js:549
      return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path),     stringToFlags(flags), mode);

Comment: @Adam: I think, it would be better if you show us some more code & full detailed error you are getting.

Answer (score -2):

mscdex is nearly right. You need to listen for the 'finish' event, not the 'close' event because that is emitted by readable streams but this is a writable stream.

And you can pass your handler to 'end' instead. See https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish

```
logStream.end(function() {
    fs.renameSync("manny_temp.json", "manny.json");
    callback(filepath);
});
```

I tried to edit mscdex's answer to this effect but this was rejected for some reason.

Edit: You'd need to define or pass in 'callback', as well as 'filepath'.

Comment: The `close` event is *not* exclusive to readable file streams. In fact, both readable and writable file streams [share the same `.close()` implementation](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/627524973a22c584fdd06c951fbe82364927a1ed/lib/fs.js#L1919), which is [where `close` is emitted](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/627524973a22c584fdd06c951fbe82364927a1ed/lib/fs.js#L1766).

Comment: I should also note that `close` events are not a part of node streams themselves, so it is up to individual streams implementations (such as the `fs` streams) to emit it where applicable.

Comment: The OP creates logStream with fs.createWriteStream, so gets a WriteStream object which is also not documented to emit 'close' events. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_writestream

Comment: `close` isn't documented under `fs.ReadStream` either. `close` *is* documented under the streams' `Readable` stream docs, so that is really just a (unintentional) documentation issue. However the `fs.ReadStream` and `fs.WriteStream` have shared `.close()` implementations for a long time, so it's safe to use in the meantime.

Comment: FWIW I've submitted an issue about the documentation [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/6484).

Comment: I would not generally recommend relying on ondocumented behaviours as they are liable to change or to go away.